# Internet Explorer JQuery animation BUG

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Hello i got this problem i got JQuery function `$(element).slideUp()` that i use to show hidden content. I got it working perfectly on FireFox, Chrome etc. but Internet Explorer break it.

When i click on element that activate slideUp action container that hold the element which will be hidden, stretch to enormous height and stays that way for few seconds and then do proper animation to hide or get stuck on that height forever. I dont know what causes that problem and i couldnt find solution for that.

Here are the boxes that resize. slideDown animation works fine but on slideUp transactions_container get stuck on like 1000px height for no reason.

```
<div class="row rec-trans-box" style="display: table;"> 
 <div class="conf-detail" style="display: none;" id="conf1">  
 </div>     
 <div class="col-md-4 no-padding auto-margin width-box" id="news_box">
 </div> 

 <div class="col-md-8 rec-trans-mainbox" id="transactions_container" style="height: auto;">                 
  <div class="rec-trans" style="height: 100%; display: block;">             
  </div>        
</div>
```

Here is JQuery. Show functions

```
$('#news_box').hide();
$('#conf1').slideDown();
```

Hiding functions

```
$('#news_box').show();
$('#conf1').slideUp();
```

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer did this happen in? And which version of jQuery are you using? If you need to support IE6/7/8, you should use the latest jQuery 1.x; the jQuery 2.x branch doesn't support those browser versions.

Comment: Im using IE 11 with JQuery 1.11.3, its browser that my company use.

Comment: Okay, doesn't sound like it's a jQuery browser compatibility issue. Could you please add the relevant code to your post so we can see if there might be an issue with it?

Comment: Well ill try its lots of code and i dont know if it will make sense.